# SQL syntax error on select between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get records which between two dates. Below is my query

```
select * from my_data 
where name = 'customer' AND 
(time between (('2021-03-24'::date - '1 month'::interval) AND '2021-03-24'::date))
```

However I'm getting a syntax error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...03-24'::date - '1 month'::interval) AND '2021-03-24'::date))
                                                                      ^
```

What is the correct way of writing the query to return rows 1 month older than a given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the parentheses:

```
select *
from my_data 
where name = 'customer' AND 
      time between '2021-03-24'::date - '1 month'::interval AND '2021-03-24'::date;
```

The specific issue is that the range for `between` does not accept parens.